# Exporting and printing matlab figure

Tags: matlab, pdf, matlab-figure

I have a Matlab figure. I need to use it as a picture so I can insert it in Word, then save that new Word document as a PDF file and then print that PDF file. I have tried saving Matlab figure as .JPG and . PNG file but the picture gets "smaller" when inserted in Word and converted to PDF and when printed, you can hardly distinguish anything. What can I do so that the quality of the figure dosen't change?

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options here.

#### Specify the Resolution

When saving the figure, by default 72 dpi is used (your screen resolution) which may causeyour images to appear small when being inserted into a Word document. Rather than using `saveas`, you can use `print` to specify the resolution of the resulting image.  For a PNG

```
print(hfig, 'filename.png', '-dpng', '-r300')   % Resolution = 300 DPI
```

Note that if you're using `print`, you will also need to specify a few other properties of the figure to get it to look similar to the on-screen appearance.

```
set(hfig, 'Units', 'inches');
pos = get(hfig, 'Position');

set(hfig, 'PaperPositionMode', 'manual', ...
          'PaperPosition', [0 0 pos(3:4)], ...
          'InvertHardCopy', 'off');
```

#### Use an EPS

If you're ultimately exporting to a PDF and your image is line art, consider exporting to an EPS (a vector-graphic). Again, this can be done using `print`.

```
print(hfig, 'filename.eps', '-depsc2')
```

#### Use `export_fig`

The FEX submission [`export_fig`](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export-fig) is a widely-recommended utility for creating figures from your MATLAB figures in a way that preserves the way that they appear within MATLAB.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to save it as a file, just copy it to the clipboard and then paste it, it will be copied as a metafile (vector graphics) that looks good when resized.  It is best to resize by dragging the corners to maintain the original aspect ratio.

After you make a figure, select from the figure menu: Edit / Copy Figure and then paste into Word or PowerPoint.  You can change some of the options for copying by selecting Edit / Copy Options... from the figure menu